# Why is local time not different from UTC in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code that makes use of `moment.js`:

```
var Now = moment();
var UTC = moment().utc();

 if (moment().isBefore(UTC)){
    $("#was").html("Time difference : " + Now.from(UTC)).fadeIn('fast');
 } else {
    $("#was").html("Time difference : " + UTC.fromNow()).fadeIn('fast');
 }
```

Result is **always**: "*A few seconds ago*". Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your last phrase belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `Now` and `UTC` will display differently, they are the same "moment in time". To understand this you have to grasp how `moment.js` works internally. Here is some [info from the official `moment.js` documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) (emphasis mine):

> By default, moment **parses and displays in local time**.
>
> If you want to **parse or display a moment in UTC**, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment().

So the difference is all in parsing and displaying. Internally, moment objects have the same timestamp. A little test to demonstrate this is to append (and run) the followin after your code:

```
console.log(Now.valueOf());
console.log(UTC.valueOf());
console.log(Now.valueOf() - UTC.valueOf());  // will be "a few secods" at most ;)
```

**Update:** If your intention was to create a moment of, say, 5 hours ago, then:

```
var hours_ago = 5;
var earlier = moment().subtract('hours', hours_ago); // 5 hours ago
var earlier_yet = moment().subtract({'days': 2, 'hours': 3}) // 2 days, 3 hours ago
```

Comment: Then the same thing would happen if we used difference between zone("+00:00") and zone("+05:00") ...   Is there a work around this to show actual difference?

Comment: Does `var ago_5h = moment().subtract('hours', 5);` cover your needs?

Comment: I will try to see what I can come up with this , but thank you for explaining how moment works that actually solves most of my problem here.