# toDate returns the Date in the users timezone instead of the parsed timezone

Tags: momentjs

My use case is that the user has a timezone specified that is different from the computer's timezone.

Calling format() on the moment object works as expected.

```
moment("2014-05-28 00:00:00 +0530").zone(-330).format()
"2014-05-28T00:00:00+05:30"
```

Now calling toDate() on the same thing I end up with the previous day.

```
moment("2014-05-28 00:00:00 +0530").zone(-330).toDate()
Tue May 27 2014 12:30:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

How do I go about getting the Date that I need ?

Thanks.

PS: I need a Date object for the jquery ui datepicker.

**Edit** 
In the meantime I'm using:

```
var zoneDiffInMinutes = value.zone(); // value is a moment object
var date = value.toDate();
var tzDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) - (zoneDiffInMinutes * 60000));
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705224/why-is-local-time-not-different-from-utc-in-moment-js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I'm using:

```
var zoneDiffInMinutes = value.zone(); // value is a moment object
var date = value.toDate();
var tzDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) - (zoneDiffInMinutes * 60000));
```